# Writing out Excel format from R

Tags: r, xls

I am trying to find out how to write out large files in Excel format from R. I have a `.RData` file and I want to write it in a proper excel file, not just tab delimited text file with `.xls` extension.

I tested 3 packages :

1. xlsx
2. dataframes2xls
3. WriteXLS

   but neither had a good success so far.

**`xlsx->`** refused to work with big files, worked with smaller ones.

**`dataframes2xls->`** didn't write out anything

**`WriteXLS ->`** too slow

I need a method that works fast, some seconds at most, and the files need to be written out so that the column types are defined and open up correctly in excel.

Any suggestion of another package? or some way of using this one of this packages to make it work properly?

Comment: This is rather vague. How "big" are these Excel files in terms of rows and columns? How do you define "fast"? I quite like the `XLConnect` package - try it and see.

Comment: "a proper excel file" ? really ambiguous , multi-sheet excel file with colored/grouped cells?

Comment: @SlowLearner this file has 45281 rows and 23 columns. Fast it means that it will take some seconds to run..

Comment: Try the RODBC package, by the way check this blog http://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/10/06/export-data-frames-to-multi-worksheet-excel-file/

Comment: Can you please describe why your worflow *must* be this way. My favourite package, `XLConnect` runs out of memory with a moderate sized data frame, but `write.csv` on a data frame this size takes about 3 seconds. Given you can easily open a `.csv` from Excel, why don't you change your workflow?

Comment: @Andrie i used write.csv and it works fine, at least in my computer, but if is a windows user? does it open correctly n all operation systems and shows all values correctly (e.g. not converting numbers to dates etc.) ??

Comment: It should do. Find a friend with a Windoze machine and ask her to test  your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `XLConnect` package, it took less than several seconds to write xlsx file for 140 thousand rows, please note that `options(java.parameters = "-Xmx2048m")` should be set before loading `XLConnect`:

```
options(java.parameters = "-Xmx2048m")

set.seed(123)
big_df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(140000), y = rnorm(140000), z = rnorm(140000))

library(XLConnect)
wb <- loadWorkbook("test.xlsx", create = TRUE)
createSheet(wb, "test")
writeWorksheet(wb, big_df, "test")
saveWorkbook(wb)
```